# How to rename Notebook in Microsoft OneNote for Mac

Tags: ms-office, onenote

Following [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-pages-sections-or-notebooks-in-onenote-for-mac-38aa7c39-6351-4a1d-b339-bf8ed4793220) I closed the Notebook in *OneNote for Mac* (version 16.52), renamed the Notebook in *OneDrive* and re-opened the renamed Notebook in *OneNote for Mac*.  Unfortunately the rename is ignored by *OneNote for Mac* and then the synchronisation fails immediately after opening as the Notebooks are inconsistently named.

Sync error:

> This section might have been deleted from the server. You can try to sync this section again, or copy your notes to another section.

I have tried to open the Notebook in *OneNote online*: the Notebook opens correctly and shows the correct new name.  I have deleted the Microsoft OneNote container in my user Library, plus any other reference I could find in my user Library related to Microsoft OneNote.  I have tried closing the Notebook in *OneNote for Mac*, opening in *OneNote online*, make changes in the Notebook so that it forces a synchronisation, and then re-opening the Notebook in *OneNote for Mac*.  The update made in *OneNote online* shows on the Mac, however changes on the Mac are not synchronised back to the online repository of the Notebook due to above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird, I'm not sure how this worked for me, but...
Essentially, I had exactly the same issue (renamed the "file" in OneDrive, opened the new file name in OneNote, but the old name was retained and synchronising updates failed). I then took the following steps:

1. I closed OneNote, went to OneDrive and copied the notebook to a new name.
   Opened OneNote, tried to open the new notebook, but OneNote couldn't even see it.
2. Closed OneNote completely.
3. Repeated steps 1 & 2
4. Opened OneNote again, and there it was - the original renamed version (the one I was trying to open & sync originally, not the copy), and syncing looked okay. I opened it (not the copy) on the web, and my changes were synchronised.
5. I deleted the copy via OneDrive.

I know - it's a reall "turn it off and on again" kind of thing, but there you are.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: These very specific instructions didn't work for me, however at one point in all the different resets I have done over a few weeks period suddenly it started working.  So I'd say the answer is mostly: "it's a real "turn it off and on again" kind of thing"